# Create chatter post with mention for API version 37.0

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-feed

I want to create chatter post with mention for API version 37.0

Have a look over this link [Chatter Api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods) Saying

> Feed item methods aren’t available in version 32.0. In version 32.0 and later, use feed element methods.

When using `postFeedElement(communityId, feedElement, feedElementFileUpload)` this method supported **API Version is 31.0–35.0**

> In version 36.0 and later, this method is no longer available because you can’t create a feed post and upload a binary file in the same call. Upload files to Salesforce first, and then use postFeedElement(communityId, feedElement) to create the feed post and attach the files.

*Then*

**How to create chatter post with mention for API version 37.0??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm) for posting a mention. However, the example pertains to older API versions. To use v37.0, you'll need to make a change to the last line. Instead of this:

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput, null);
```

use this:

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the documentation still references the incorrect function signature in, at least, the example titled: "Post a Feed Element with a Mention"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm